# Kentico MultiFileUploader.ashx timeout for large files

Tags: kentico

I am getting a 504 Gateway timeout when I tried to upload a large file. In my case, I am getting errors if the file size is larger than 500MB. Here's the message from the network log.

> EventUrl: /CMSModules/Content/CMSPages/Authenticated/MultiFileUploader.ashx?InstanceGuid=f0c59348-4637-4f2e-9d13-7af68a241fed&filename=TearsOfSteel.mp4&FilesCount=1&ResizeArgs=0;0;0&**complete=true**&StartByte=184549376&AttachmentArgs=DocumentID%7c100581%7cDocumentParentNodeID%7c100580%7cNodeClassName%7cCMS.MenuItem%7cAttachmentGUIDColumnName%7cVODVideoUpload%7cAttachmentGUID%7c00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7cAttachmentGroupGUID%7c00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7cFormGUID%7c00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7cIsFieldAttachment%7cTrue%7cFullRefresh%7cFalse%7cHash%7c0a173cf90a038346b2b8e611a31c08e613186f78d4bfd2eb98732a0eef0a5f0f&AdditionalParameters=SourceType%7cAttachment%7cParentElementID%7cm_c_f_VODVideoUpload_VODVideoUpload%7cIsInsertMode%7cTrue%7cAfterSaveJavascript%7c%7cTargetFolderPath%7c%7cTargetFileName%7c%7cIncludeNewItemInfo%7cTrue%7cOnlyImages%7cFalse%7cRaiseOnClick%7cFalse%7cTargetAliasPath%7c%7cTargetCulture%7c%7cEventTarget%7c%7cHash%7cb9038c2880b35dd13b237caad502b2fd6527668c3265a423f35bb4712dca100a&CurrentFileIndex=1&FileSize=185765954&AllowedExtensions=mp4|Hash|155cb9811186cec9af3ad6dfc9474eca4f9ccd28cd5a1bf6bd0a0dd01e3a028a

I have tried to increased ConnectionString timeout to 600 and httpRuntime executionTimeout to 60000.

[image]

Response Header

```
content-length: 534 content-type: text/html date: Tue, 16 Mar 2021
07:00:12 GMT server: awselb/2.0
```

Response

```
<html> <head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head> <body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I would give it a try and increase also the request and content length as described in this article: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/tips-for-uploading-and-staging-large-files

Comment: @jurajo, yes i have followed the suggestions. After doing extensive investigation, i have identified the root cause. For my case, we are using AWS ELB in between, so the timeout is coming the ELB. The issue solved by increasing the **Idle timeout**. By default, ELB Idle timeout is 60 seconds.